# Adding php code to renaming file while/ after uploading

Tags: php, image-uploading, file-rename

I am beginner to php and learning my ways around it. I know functions but nothing working out for me, making too many mistakes. If someone please help. Below is the part of the code of Image uploading function, I need to add function so that it renames the file by replacing spaces with hyphen (-) [after / while uploading of image file)

```
if(isset($input['pic'])){

if(isset($input['img_url']) && $input['img_url'] != ''){
input['pic_url'] = ImageHandler::uploadImage($input['img_url'], 'images',  Helper::slugify($input['title']), 'url');

} else if(isset($input['pic_url'])){
$input['pic_url'] = ImageHandler::uploadImage(Input::file('pic_url'), 'images');

$input['pic'] = 1;
}
```

Thanks

EB

Comment: If you want to replace a character, use `str_replace()`

Comment: source not clear, what u doing in Helper::slugify() function??
add full source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use:

```
if (!empty($input['img_url'])) { ... }
```

instead of..

```
if (isset($input['img_url']) && $input['img_url'] != '') { ... }
```

As second please make sure before posting a question, if you posted all information what is necessary to answer your question. For example, in your code you're using *ImageHandler::uploadImage()* it's not clear what this class it's function does. Altho I can guess what the parameters are. Something like..?

```
ImageHandler::uploadImage($file, $folder, $name, $type);
```

Anyway I'm not sure, but if I'm right than try to modify the thrid parameter *$name* to your needs.

Not bad to mention, but this happens after the file has been uploaded to the temporary directory on the server after completion it will be moved to the selected directory with the choosen filename.

Comment: thanks. I didn't realize that I forgot to put the other part of code and left the table for some air. Amazingly your entire guess was like 100% correct - so taking your 'guessed' code and using str_replace - it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace(" ", "-", end(explode("/", $image_path)));
```

Comment: Not exactly the same way however str_replace worked fine now in ImageHandler function. and Sorry I forgot to add ImageHandler code - does not matter now as it is fine (now)